# Create an XML from an Image

Tags: android, xml, mask

Hi there I have the following image as a background:

[image: Background Image] and I would like to know if it possible to create an xml file to replace it, so the idea would be to use a gradient from some position to the top and the rest just a solid colour (black)... is that possible?? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

First of all thanks for your help. To be more specific with my question, the goal to replace this image with an xml file is to make faster the MaskableFrameLayout of https://github.com/christophesmet/android_maskable_layout

So my code example is the following:

```
<com.christophesmet.android.views.maskableframelayout.MaskFrameLayout
android:id="@+id/lytMask"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:src="@drawable/gradient_mask"
>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recAlphaMask"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

I want to mask the top of the list when it is scrolled, the example works fine but if I use the image it's quite slow a very poor performance, and maybe if I replace the image by an xml is gonna be faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try any of this or you can generate your own online. There is a tool to generate gradient online at :-** http://angrytools.com/gradient/

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <gradient 
    android:type="linear"
    android:centerX="11%" 
    android:startColor="#FF8C8C8C" 
    android:centerColor="#FF8C8C8C" 
    android:endColor="#FF000000" 
    android:angle="270"/>
    </shape>

    -------------------------------------------------
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <gradient 
    android:type="radial"
    android:centerX="50%" 
    android:centerY="50%" 
    android:startColor="#FF8C8C8C" 
    android:centerColor="#FF8C8C8C" 
    android:endColor="#FF000000" 
    android:gradientRadius="11"/>
    </shape>
```

Below is screen shot of setting I was using to generate above xml

[image]

Comment: If that solved your problem please accept the answer and close the thread.

Comment: Not yet, I've added some extra comments to my question, thanks

Comment: Hi @hitesh-sahu I've fixed my problem just adjusting the android:centerX and the android:centerColor so that's done! thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Say that your root view is a `LinearLayout`, you can set the background to `@drawable/gradient_background` where `gradient_background.xml` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#474946"
        android:endColor="#181818"
        android:centerY="0.1"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Where `startColor` is the starting color, `endColor` is the ending color, and `centerY` is the position where the colors merge (value between 0 and 1.0)